# Did :pre & :post defn conditions become obsolete after core.spec was introduced?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure.spec

I'm new to Clojure and at first sight from what I see core.spec does everything that :pre & :post defn conditions is used for PLUS much more.

I understand that core.spec was introduced much later(and still in alpha/beta phase) and :pre & :post defn conditions existed for much longer - maybe that's the reason why pre/post are still not considered as obsolete approach?

Is there something that :pre/:post offers that I can't get from core.spec?

Thanks

Comment: "Does core.spec provide a strict superset of the capabilities of :pre and :post defn conditions?" might be less opinion-based / more concrete. This wording implies a burden of proof on anyone choosing not to use a library that's outside the core language's ongoing compatibility guarantees to justify that choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people prefer [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) to Clojure Spec (both have their strengths).  `clojure.test.check` is also very powerful.

The main point here is that all of the above ***only apply*** (normally) when running unit tests.  The `:pre` and `:post` checks apply ***always*** when the function executes.

Another tool I like is the [Plumatic Schema](http://plumatic.github.io/schema/schema.core.html#var-validate) function `validate`.  You can find a [similar (but better) function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.199/api/tupelo.core#validate) at `tupelo.core/validate`.

Comment: "all of the above only apply (normally) when running unit tests" but you call `clojure.spec/instrument` and those checks will be enabled in production as well, right? Or is considered to be an antipattern in Clojure? Just wondering

Comment: You can use instrument in production but it introduces a checking overhead that you may not want. In addition, the instrumentation testing can cause generative testing to be performed "at runtime" if you have fspec'd arguments on your higher-order functions that you've instrumented, so you need to be careful about that. The general guidance is to use instrument only in dev/test.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the official documentation, you can use both together: 
https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_using_spec_for_validation